# How do I make a POST request with open-uri?

Tags: ruby, open-uri

Is it possible to make a POST request from Ruby with open-uri?

Answer (score 35, accepted):

Unfortunately `open-uri` only supports the `GET` verb.

You can either drop down a level and use `net/http`, or use `rest-open-uri`, which was designed to support `POST` and other verbs. You can do `gem install rest-open-uri` to install it.

Answer (score 17):

```
require 'open-uri'
require 'net/http'
params = {'param1' => 'value1', 'param2' => 'value2'}
url = URI.parse('http://thewebsite.com/thepath')
resp, data = Net::HTTP.post_form(url, params)
puts resp.inspect
puts data.inspect
```

It worked for me :)

Comment: -1 This isn't using OpenURI to handle the connection, it's using Net::HTTP. In this example, OpenURI is only being used to load the URI module.

Comment: Also you've declared `params` then referenced `query`

Comment: doesn't matter if its using or not. if open-uri cannot do it, this answer will help a lot of people. no way to downvote this answer

Comment: What is `data`? There is nothing in the docs which indicates what that is. https://ruby-doc.org/stdlib-2.7.4/libdoc/net/http/rdoc/Net/HTTP.html#method-c-post_form

Answer (score 10):

I'd also really recommend [rest-client](https://github.com/rest-client/rest-client). It's a great base for writing an API client.

Comment: Kinda confused visiting the main site posted above - is this a gem I have to compile myself and include?

Comment: I'm not sure, used it a lot. Simple for simple use case. But I was left with the impressions that its API is a little bit inconsistent and to achieve more complicated stuff, one has to go into implementation details. Like stream copying for example.

Answer (score 0):

As simple as it gets:

```
require 'open-uri'
require 'net/http'

response = Net::HTTP.post_form(URI.parse("https://httpbin.org/post"), { a: 1 })

puts response.code
puts response.message
puts response.body
```

I recommend using `response.methods - Object.methods` to see all the available methods, e.g. `message`, `header,`

**Bonus**: POST / DELETE requests:

```
puts Net::HTTP.new("httpbin.org").post("/post", "a=1").body
puts Net::HTTP.new("httpbin.org").delete("/delete").body
```