# Why is IO.popen hanging on a valid command?

Tags: ruby, curl, stream, popen

I'm using `IO.popen` to run a `curl` command (octet stream POST). I copy the command and run it on a command line and it works. Running it in Ruby with `popen`, however, causes the stream to end unexpectedly on my server and the Ruby script just hangs, with `curl` endlessly running.

Here's what I'm doing:

```
curl = "curl "
curl += "--cookie \"JSESSIONID=#{@sessionid}\" "
curl += "-H \"Content-type:application/octet-stream\" "
curl += "-X POST "
curl += "-o \"#{responseFile}\" "
curl += "--data-binary \"@#{filename}\" "
curl += "\"#{url}\""

puts "command: #{curl}"

IO.popen(curl, "r") { |out|
  out.readlines
}
# Script never makes it to here
```

I must be doing something silly. What is it?

[Here is the stdout from curl.](http://pastebin.com/FA54XvX9)

I am using Ruby 1.8.6

Comment: I piped both stdout and stderr to a file, which is where that pastebin link came from.

Comment: Yes my server fails to read the stream because it reaches eof unexpectedly, so I get the error message that I send back from the server. It fails gracefully, but fails nonetheless.

Comment: Have you tried different versions/releases of Ruby?

Comment: Why do you need to open a pipe? Try `\`#{curl}\`` instead?

Answer (score 0):

The `popen` also gives curl a pipe to read *from*, as this example shows:

```
$ echo -e 'foo\nbar\nzoo' | \
  ruby -e 'pipe = IO.popen("grep oo", "r") {|out| p out.readlines}'
["foo\n", "zoo\n"]
```

I guess that curl wants to POST to the server also from stdin, where nothing is coming from, so it comes to a 30s timeout.

Comment: The man information for the -data parameter (to which --data-binary is similar) implies that using "@" before the parameter causes curl to post from the file instead of stdin.

Answer (score 0):

Rather than write your own version of a wheel, why not take advantage of the many gems for Ruby that do the same thing?

I'd recommend and [typhoeus](https://github.com/dbalatero/typhoeus), [curb](https://github.com/taf2/curb) for starting points. Also the built-in [OpenURI](http://www.ruby-doc.org/stdlib-1.9.3/libdoc/open-uri/rdoc/) works nicely for most "get" type needs.

There's a [useful thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/242602/how-do-i-make-a-post-request-with-open-uri) on SO for this post requests also.

Comment: Yea, don't I know it. Unfortunately my code runs in a Ruby environment that is missing the standard libraries... This is actually the entire reason I had to write this little nugget. I have used RestClient in the past with great success.

Comment: BUT if you can either compile the standard C extensions on Mac for Ruby 1.8.5 (I tried and couldn't get them all) OR find me an HTTP library that doesn't rely on any C extensions or features >1.8.5, let me know =)