# POST with ruby: best practise and how to?

Tags: ruby, post, rubygems, httprequest, open-uri

I want to make a simple post request using ruby.
At first I tried it with the gem open-uri. But this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/242602/how-do-i-make-a-post-request-with-open-uri) to a so- question says that it doesn't work. So instead of this I want to use the rest-open-uri gem as recommended in the post.
But how does it work? and how does it work using a proxy?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

http://ruby-doc.org/stdlib-2.0/libdoc/net/http/rdoc/Net/HTTP.html#method-i-post

From the docs, a summary:

```
response = http.post('/cgi-bin/search.rb', 'query=foo')
```

Use case:

```
# using block
File.open('result.txt', 'w') {|f|
  http.post('/cgi-bin/search.rb', 'query=foo') do |str|
    f.write str
  end
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Couldn't you just use Ruby's stdlib? [Here](http://ruby-doc.org/stdlib-2.0/libdoc/net/http/rdoc/Net/HTTP.html) you have some nice examples for ruby 2.0.